# Iterating Through A List

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to iterate through this list and get the value for one doctor at a time.

There are multiples per each doctor in the excel document, but I want the output to be the doctors one at  time.

In the excel document, it goes HILL CANN CANN HILL and that's currently what I'm getting back.

But I want to iterate per doctor so it would go HILL HILL CANN CANN

```
        Dim physname As New List(Of String)()

    'Get all of the data from tblPhysician that you will use and put into a list for searching the excel file
    Sql = "select * from tblPhysician "
    conn = New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    comm = New OdbcCommand(Sql, conn)
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader()

    'Populate the physname list with the doctors names
    While (dr.Read())
        physname.Add(dr("PhysicianName").ToString())
    End While

range = oxlsheet.UsedRange
    For rcnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
        For ccnt = 2 To 6
            varray = CType(range.Cells(rcnt, ccnt), Excel.Range)
            If (IsNumeric(varray.value)) Then
                temp = varray.value.ToString
            Else
                temp = varray.value
            End If

            'Iterate through physname list for each doctor in the list
            For Each doctor As String In physname

                If (rcnt > 8) Then
                    If (IsNumeric(varray.Columns(4).value)) Then
                        temp2 = varray.Columns(4).value.ToString
                    Else
                        temp2 = varray.Columns(4).value
                    End If

                    'If the name in the excel column matches, write out the name and value
                    If (temp2 = doctor) Then
                        Console.WriteLine(varray.Columns(4).value)
                        Console.WriteLine(varray.Columns(5).value)
                        Console.ReadLine()
                    End If


                End If

            Next

        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Do you need to *read them in* in order and print each item as it's read, or can you read everything in, sort, and then output each item? Also I'm guessing this is homework.

Comment: Well i'm going to eventually add up some other information in the excel file. So I thought that iterating through each doctor like this would give me information PER doctor PER time through the list. No, not homework. Just trying to broaden my knowledge of vb

Answer (score 1):

Here's some examples using LINQ. I highly suggest you read up on it, as there's some powerful stuff in there. Learning LINQ as well as lambda expressions and anonymous methods/functions can be extremely helpful!

```
Imports System
IMports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim physname as new List(Of String) From {"HILL", "CANN", "CANN", "HILL"}

        ' Output the raw list as a baseline...
        Console.WriteLine("Raw list of physicians:")
        For Each physician as string in physname
            Console.WriteLine(physician)
        next

        ' Using Distinct will select each physician once...
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Distinct physicians:")
        For Each physician as String in physname.Distinct()
            Console.WriteLine(physician)
        next

        ' Sort the list in place and then display...
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Raw physicians list ordered:")
        physname.Sort() 
        For Each physician as String in physname
            Console.WriteLine(physician)
        next
    End Sub
End Module
```

This example doesn't directly fix your problem in a sort of copy-and-paste-into-your-project fashion, but it illustrates a couple ways to iterate through a generic List.